# Node JS Cluster to use 4 core of cpu at the same time

Tags: node.js, nodes, child-process

**Server code**

```
module.exports = function(cluster){
    let express = require('express')
    let app = express()
    app.get('/',function(req, res){

      console.log('Worker %d started!'+new Date(), cluster.worker.id);

      sleep(60000)

      for(var i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) {}

      res.end('Hello from Worker ' + cluster.worker.id);
      console.log('Worker %d returned!'+new Date(), cluster.worker.id);
    });
    app.listen(8080,function(){
      console.log('Application started! Worker %d started!, process %d', cluster.worker.id, cluster.worker.process.pid);
    });
    function sleep(miliseconds) {
        var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

        while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
        }
     }
  }
```

**Cluster Code**

```
let cluster = require('cluster');
let app = require('./index');
cluster.schedulingPolicy = cluster.SCHED_RR;
if(cluster.isMaster){
  let cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length;
  for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function() {
    cluster.fork();
  });
}else{
  app(cluster);
}
cluster.on('fork', function(worker) {
console.log('forked -> Worker %d', worker.id);
});
```

-When I am hitting multiple API on default express port 8080 then it is using only one core of CPU where it waits for the process of the first hit and then the next request will be executed.
-Why Cluster not using the other core of CPU to process 4(for quad-core CPU) request parallelly.

Comment: How did you test that? using browsers or something else?

Comment: Using a shell script with multiple curl requests.
Here is the code in sh file:-
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080
curl http://localhost:8080

Comment: Are you sure these requests are parallel or execute one by one

Comment: Thanks, Timothy you are right, these requests are not running parallelly because all the request are kept in a single sh file which will be executing as a single process by Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than running a script from a single tab, run it with the multiple command tabs, all the CPU of your computer will be utilized, you can check them in system monitor.